# Resource is not supported in this region cloudformation EFSFileSystem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've encountered following error message in AWS CloudFormation about `EFSFileSystem`.

```
  EFSMountTargetSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      GroupDescription: Security group for mount target
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '2049'
        ToPort: '2049'
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  EFSFileSystem:
    Type: AWS::EFS::FileSystem
    Properties:
      PerformanceMode: generalPurpose
  EFSMountTargetA:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref 'EFSFileSystem'
      SubnetId: !Ref 'VPCSubnetDataA'
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EFSMountTargetSecurityGroup']
  EFSMountTargetB:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref 'EFSFileSystem'
      SubnetId: !Ref 'VPCSubnetDataB'
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref 'EFSMountTargetSecurityGroup']
```

Please let me know how to use `EFSFileSystem` or replace in that region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS `Elastic File System` is not currently available in Mumbai, Hong Kong, Beijing, Ningxia, Osaka, Paris or Stockholm.  I can't tell from your `CloudFormation` snippet if you're trying to deploy in one of those regions.

**References**

[AWS Regional Product Services](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/)